Using the StringLength (or MaxLength) attribute in ASP.NET MVC, I am not receiving client-side validation
when using StringLength or MaxLength attribute, it only prevents further text input after the defined limit is reached, and
without displaying a validation message.
Code (model):
 [Display(Name = "Naslovnik")]
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UI_Validation_RequiredValidator",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceUI))] //custom error message
 [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Naslovnik can be a maximum of 100 characters long.")]
 //[MaxLength(20)]
 public string Naslovnik { get; set; } = string.Empty;

how to enable the validation message on the client-side?

I had a test in my side with data annotation  [Required, StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Naslovnik must be between 10 and 100 characters long.")] and I found that this will auto add maxlength="20" into the input field so that we are not able to add string longer than 20, therefore we can't trigger the error for longer then max length. https://i.sstatic.net/XIua10xc.png   If I delete the maxlength="20" in the html manually, I can get the error.
